# How to display Filename with my awk script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cgi

I have this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /home/XXXXX/Desktop/XXXXX/test_script/*.csv | awk -F',|;' '{print $1","$2","$5","$6","$7}' | awk -F',|;' '{

print "LPARS : " $2
print "RAM : " $3
print "CPU 1 : " $4
print "CPU 2 : " $5
print ""
}'
```

I have many csv files like this :

```
MO2PPC20,miaibv177,9,0.1,1
MO2PPC20,mo2vio20d,6,0.5,2
MO2PPC20,mo2vio20c,6,0.5,2
MO2PPC20,miaibv141,142,1.2,6
MO2PPC20,mplaix0267,60,1.5,4
MO2PPC20,mplaix0094,39,0.3,5
MO2PPC20,miaibv106,105,2.0,4
MO2PPC20,miaibya06,91,2.0,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv264,79,0.4,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv231,62,1.2,3
MO2PPC20,mplaix0147,69,0.3,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv95,60,0.6,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv161,60,1.2,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv246,12,0.5,1
MO2PPC20,mplaix0088,130,1.5,11
MO2PPC20,mplaix0306,180,0.5,3
MO2PPC20,mplaix0087,100,0.4,4
MO2PPC20,miaibv182,5,0.5,1
MO2PPC20,mo2vio20b,7,1.0,2
MO2PPC20,mo2vio20a,7,1.0,2
MO2PPC20,mplaix0329,50,0.6,4
MO2PPC21,mo2vio21b,6,1.5,3
MO2PPC21,mo2vio21a,6,1.5,3
MO2PPC21,mplaix0190,243,4.9,30
MO1PPC17,miaibe03,25,null,3
MO1PPC17,miaiba12,17,null,2
MO1PPC17,miaibf03,30,null,3
MO1PPC17,miaibc05,40,null,2
MO1PPC17,miaibd05,0.25,null,1
MO1PPC17,miaibe04,14,null,5
MO2PPC17,miaibe01,28,null,1
MO2PPC17,miaiba05,18,null,2
MO2PPC17,miaibe02,34,null,4
MO2PPC17,miaibd04,27,null,1
MO2PPC17,miaibc07,25,null,2
```

If I run my script with this command :

```
for file in $(ls *.csv); do ./test3.sh $file; done
```

The result is :

```
LPARS : miaiba05
RAM : 18
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2

LPARS : miaibe02
RAM : 34
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 4

LPARS : miaibd04
RAM : 27
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 1

LPARS : miaibc07
RAM : 25
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2

LPARS : 65-6EF5E
RAM : 0
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 0

LPARS : miaibf03_rec
RAM : 0.25
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 3
```

The problem is : I have 276 CSv files, my script analyze all of them and display informations like above. But, I don't know how I can know in which files are the informations displayed.

I would like something like :

```
File : XXXX.csv

LPARS : miaiba05
RAM : 18
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2

LPARS : miaibe02
RAM : 34
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 4

LPARS : miaibd04
RAM : 27
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 1


File : XXXXXX.csv

LPARS : miaibc07
RAM : 25
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 2

LPARS : 65-6EF5E
RAM : 0
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 0

LPARS : miaibf03_rec
RAM : 0.25
CPU 1 : null
CPU 2 : 3
```

Can you tell me how I can do this ?

Comment: Maybe `for file in $(ls *.csv); do echo "File:" $file ; ./test3.sh $file; done`

Comment: +1 for doing this from bash, however you should avoid parsing the output of ls, it's prone to error. I suggest using `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -print -exec ./test3.sh {} \;` which will for each csv in the current directory 1) print the file name 2) execute `./test3.sh` with the filepath as parameter. If you want your exact format with 'File :' before the filename you can use `-printf` followed by a format specification instead of print, e.g. `-printf 'File : %f\n'`

Comment: @Aaron, that works well ! Thank you ! How Can I add -printf 'File : %f\n' in this command ?
Like this : find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -print -exec  -print 'File : %f\n' ./test3.sh {} \; ?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -printf 'File : %f\n' -exec ./test3.sh {} \;`

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate but it does not apply. The duplicate post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231808/how-to-display-filename-from-a-column-using-awk) relies on running `awk` with a specific file (or a pattern of files), but this question is running using piped output from `cat` so `awk` will have no concept of "file". Instead, it's just processing a stream of data.